# npm packages issues after update?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

Every time I update my angular project dependencies using `npm` or `ncu` I spend a lot of time fixing issues about package versions incompatibilities. Is their a coherent way to update all npm packages without injecting any problems ?

Comment: you can use `npm-check`. Check it out: https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check It offers detailed info like backwards compatibility, so this way you know which package is safe to update and which one may cause breaking changes.

Comment: it's not only about breaking changes but also, dependencies between packages, package x depends on version 1 of package z, package y depends on version 0.5 of the same package .....

Comment: I'm pretty sure `npm-check` can do that stuff, too. I've been updating my projects with it and I never had any problems that you've described.